# Xubuntu 14.04 display window when charger is plugged/unplugged

Tags: ati, xubuntu

I have an Acer Aspire V3-551G laptop with Xubuntu 14.04 x64. Everything is great, but when I plug the laptop in, or unplug it, I get a window showing menus and stuff would be seen in Settings > Display - like this:

[image]

It's not a major issue, but it's annoying. Any way it can be fixed? It's not an installation issue - I had it with a previous installation as well.

Laptop specs:

- AMD A8-4500M x4 @ 1.9 Ghz
- AMD Radeon 7670M (dedicated) + 7640G (integrated) graphics
- 8 GB RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, running **Xubuntu 14.04** on a AO-D255. every time I'd push the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and left or right arrows to control brightness for every time I'd hit the button the **'Display settings**' window would appear. Finally I was able to find this solution and seems to be working fine. I take no credit whatsoever. it worked for me, hopefully for you too.

1. Move the original file (in case you decide to revert the changes;  yes, it is the `xfce4-display-settings`):

   `sudo mv /usr/bin/xfce4-display-settings /usr/bin/xfce4-display-settings.original`
2. Create a fake file:

   `sudo cp /bin/true  /usr/bin/xfce4-display-settings`

This fake `xfce4-display-settings` (native code) just returns `true` to keep the calling application happy. (I don't know which daemon keeps calling it).

3. Logoff/logon; Enjoy XFCE4. Of course your "Display" in xfce settings won't work now, so you'll want to install **'lxrandr'** via Software Center to get the functionality. It's icon will be the same but called "Monitor Settings"

You may have to repeat this after distribution upgrade."

Comment: good to know! share it if you can. I'm there's more people who could use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with fresh XUbuntu 15.10. The workaround for bug #1306959 works for me (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1306959).

In short, you should disable keyboard shortcuts for "xfce-display-settings --minimal". Chances are you don't use them anyway.